# Heroku deploy using ts-node

Tags: angular, heroku, angular-universal, ts-node

I am trying to deploy a sample of the [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) in Heroku.

The task `npm start` fails because it does not recognize ts-node.

Is there a way to make deployment on Heroku work using ts-node?

Answer (score 18):

You can create a `Procfile` with

```
web: npm start
```

And have your start script to run ts-node

```
"start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
```

And install typescript and ts-node on your dependencies

```
"ts-node": "^3.3.0",
"typescript": "^2.4.2"
```

Comment: I get this error since the last build, and did not change `ts-node`. However, ts-node is in `"devDependencies"` and not `dependencies` in package.json, and was it before the error. I deleted  `@babel/core` npm package.

Comment: I think the `devdep` is my problem as seen [here further down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70891715/1705829)

Answer (score 3):

You can't deploy `ts-node` to heroku directly. either build your own [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) or just compile typescript to javascript. I recommend the latter. Just run the command `tsc -p .` on publish.

**Edit** You can also create a file called `index.js` and add the following:

```
require('ts-node/register');
require('./server.ts');
```

Then it should work. Don't forget to run `npm install --save-dev ts-node` as well.

**This is not recommended in production environment. Use it only in development.**

Comment: Hello Louy,

Thank you for your answer.I will try this out. Regarding the latest statement, what is not safe? Using heroku to run the typescript app in production?

Comment: Your suggestion works nicely locally but I still get an Application Error on heroku.

I have in my package.json all the dependencies and the follwoing settings

"main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.7"
  },

Comment: From the logs I get the following : 

Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'

Comment: I meant you shouldn't use "ts-node" in production. performance-wise it's a bad idea. To get it to work in heroku run this: `npm install --save ts-node`. What I suggest is doing a build step before running the app in heroku.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help! I am only running as a development so I guess its fine.

Comment: @Louy could you please explain why "performance-wise it's a bad idea"? I thought that ts-node will parse the typescript once, and then run the code without any different than javascript?

Comment: @zixia it will. it's just the parsing step; plus it will have the TS compiler in memory all the time.

Comment: @Louy got it, thanks. so if I do not mind slow on start time and waste some memory, it should be ok. good news for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

package.json :

```
"start":"ts-node index.ts",
"dependencies": { "ts-node" : "~<version number>" }
```

work for me :)

Comment: How, what build pack are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve problem in `heroku` related to missing `ts-node` you need to build your TypeScript code using `tsc` command in your `package.json`.

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "tsc",
  }
```

Then in `Procfile` you can use `node` command to run files that Heroku build for you by ruunning `build` command in `package.json`.

```
web: node dist/src/server.js
```

Personally, I think that's a best solution for deployment a TypeScript-based application to Heroku, if you need also `tsconfig.json` you can take a look for mine.

```
{
  "extends": "@araclx/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "lib": ["ES2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm late, but I was running into the same issue this week and this is what I've done to solve the issue by gathering multiple solutions in the web. Hope it helps someone:

Added the node and yarn or npm versions to `package.json`

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.14.0",
    "yarn": "1.x"
  },
```

Added ts-node and typescript to the project dependencies on the `package.json`

```
"ts-node": "^9.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Added the `postinstall` script that is called after the yarn or npm install called by Heroku, this will build your app on the chosen destination folder (dist in this case)

And changed the start script to server the compiled app instead of the TS one

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "tsc",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
  },
```

Pointed to the start script on the `PROCFILE`

```
web: yarn start
```

And finally this is the `tsconfig.json` where you can choose the build destination `"outDir": "dist",`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "target": "es2018",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "es2018", "esnext.asynciterable"],
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For unknown reasons Heroku prunes **ts-node** as dev dependency even if you listed it in *dependencies* instead of *devDependencies*. What should you do is to instruct Heroku not to prune devDependencies with the command:

```sh
  $ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this issue in 2022, and this was the top answer, so i am adding my solution.

#### First; to dispel the myth you shouldn't use ts-node in production . .

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789609/1205637) from [@Benny Neugebauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451634/benny-neugebauer) quoted here:

> According to Blake Embrey, the author of [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), [you can use it in production](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/104#issuecomment-250252708) BUT you should use it with the `--transpile-only flag.
>
> Example:
>
> ```bash
> ts-node --transpile-only ./src/start.ts
> ```

Additionally, you should remove `.ts` from `"start": "src/start.ts"` in `package.json` and add typings [as per the typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

```json
...
    "start":   "ts-node --transpile-only ./src/start",
    "typings": "src/start",
...
```

AND you also follow the instructions to have your tsconfig file include the following:

```json
    "compilerOptions": {
...
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": false,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
...
    },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

and you still get an error

#### The Real Problem:

If you are using a basic configuration for a `heroku-22` server, `free` or `hobby` and switch from a node to TS build, you may notice the errors on production after deployment and startup that look something like this:

```bash
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
 server.ts(1,29): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'body-parser'. '/app/node_modules/body-parser/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/body-parser` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'body-parser';`
 src/app.ts(2,26): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/app/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
...
diagnosticCodes: [ 7016, 7016, 2307, 7016 ]
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
...
```

The issue is that Heroku Buildpack `heroku/nodejs` is what is used by the [angular/universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) uses does not have the ability to run `ts-node` without one extra step...

```bash
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false --app <YOUR_APP_NAME>
```

Mentioned by [@anynomius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12794359/anynomius) in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444476/1205637) is what finally helped me and fixed the issues I was having.

Answer (score 1):

For our project, the problem was, that ts-node was only in `devDependencies` in the `package.json`, but Heroku needs this dependency at runtime so it should be added in `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution that work for me

> Step: 1 - Install below two package

```
npm i ts-node typescript --save-prod
```

Step 2: - Add the Below script to package.json inside scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm index.js",
    "heroku-start": "ts-node \"./src/server.ts\"",
}
```

Step 3: - Add the below command in your Procfile (which exists at your root level)

```
web: npm run heroku-start
```

> Step 4: Commit your changes and deploy on Heroku

[image]