# Why do I obtain this error when deploying app to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

I am getting some kind of error when deploying my app to heroku using git hub. The problem is, I don't understand the heroku logs and the entailing errors. Here is the heroku log:

```
Marcuss-MacBook-Pro:Weather-App marcushurney$ heroku logs
2016-01-05T14:37:27.798077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-01-05T14:37:27.798377+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-01-05T14:37:27.786949+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.1.1
2016-01-05T14:37:27.786556+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-01-05T14:37:27.787856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
2016-01-05T14:37:28.776245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-05T14:37:28.789412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-05T17:27:16.684869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-05T17:27:17.853743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-01-05T17:27:20.423495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.1.1
2016-01-05T17:27:20.423130+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-01-05T17:27:20.424111+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
2016-01-05T17:27:20.425937+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-01-05T17:27:20.422441+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
2016-01-05T17:27:20.426242+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-01-05T17:27:20.426432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-01-05T17:27:20.426634+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You have to inform heroku where to start : `missing script: start`. In your package.json, you should have something like [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Where `index.js` is your entry point.

As an [alternative](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type), you can specify in `Procfile`:

```
web: node index.js
```

##### How to use both

If you still want to use the start script from within the Procfile:

```
web: npm start
```

In this case, you can still feature your start script from
the package.json file as it is the usual way to proceed and it will be taken into account by Heroku.

Comment: That fixed things up!

Comment: @LMeyer it still doesn't fix it for me. Any ideas? I already included the start in the package.json

Comment: @TheProgrammerG Pretty sure if you added the start, you don't have `missing script: start` in the logs. What do you have ?

Comment: You saved me so much time! Thanks!

Comment: what if it's a typescript + node, express app?

Comment: What if my site has an index.html, but no index.js? Would I just write `"main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }` and add a starter index.js file just for Heroku? But then what about this line? `res.render('pages/index')`

Comment: @edison why would you use a `html` file in a `node` app and not a starting `js file`? Do you have a static webserver serving only html? Then use npm package `http-server` and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620425/1705829)

Comment: I would only link to the second link where the `start` key of `scripts` in the package.json is explained. The first link explains `build` which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @uber, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45742138/1705829) for your answer, just install `ts-node` and `typescript` locally and adapt your `scripts,start` entry in `package.json.

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

Comment: @gunslingor I like the first option because it the usual way to launch the application from the npm perspective. The second option could be more confusing for those who are not familiar with Heroku. However, if you have both a web and a worker at the same time in your application, the second option is necessary. I'll update the answer for the case where you want to use the start script with the Procfile.

Answer (score 6):

My silly mistake was that I was pushing the master branch to Heroku while my changes were in another branch!

Make sure that you merge your latest branch with your master branch first

```
> git checkout master

> git merge your-latest-branch

> git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, [changing](https://github.com/xameeramir/Bot-x-Skype/commit/ef9c4342a801efd6f3236ee1be093dd3428e0918) this:

```
"scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
```

to this:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node app.js"
    },
```

was the solution

Answer (score 3):

For some reason pushing the start script to top fixed the problem

So instead of

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node app.js"
}
```

I did

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "jest"

}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Wasn't working until I tried that. Also I had to add the Procfile file with "web: node app.js"

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar kind of errors for my node js app while publishing it to heroku.com

First create a procfile, procfile is a simple text file but without any extension.

Place only one line in procfile as of now.

```
web: npm start
```

Now create the package.json file using command

```
npm init
```

once your package.json file got created please place the start property inside scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

now commit all (procfile/package.json) pending files. and deploy app again from heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on this trying to deploy my server with heroku after several troubleshooting. The changes i made to my package.json which includes creating a start property into your script;

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node app.js"
},
```

After making the changes, ensure your Procfile without extension has this one line;

```
  web: node app.js (Depends on your server file).
```

Then you can proceed to commit your files.

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was using nodemon.js so I included it in the package.json as following:
"scripts"

```
 "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "nodemon index.js",
     },
```

But I got this Heroku error:

> 2022-01-06T11:51:55.044364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `npm start` 2022-01-06T11:51:57.390306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
> ERR! missing script: start 2022-01-06T11:51:57.398106+00:00
> app[web.1]:  2022-01-06T11:51:57.398334+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A
> complete log of this run can be found in:
> 2022-01-06T11:51:57.398402+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-06T11_51_57_391Z-debug.log
> 2022-01-06T11:51:57.598054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-01-06T11:51:57.882212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-01-06T11:51:57.953568+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-01-06T11:52:00.240909+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `npm start` 2022-01-06T11:52:02.010859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
> ERR! missing script: start 2022-01-06T11:52:02.014370+00:00
> app[web.1]: 2022-01-06T11:52:02.014567+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A
> complete log of this run can be found in:
> .................................etc

I found out that Heroku uses "npm start" to run our app meanwhile I didn't include it in the package.json; so included it as the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Then restarted the git processes:

```
-heroku restart
-heroku git:remote -a app_name
-git add .
-git commit -am "Your commit"
-git push heroku master
```

And everything worked well.