# Getting error: "npm ERR! missing script: start", yet start script is there

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

```
{
  "name": "oculus_scraper_node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0"
  }
}
```

When using heroku and checking if it deployed properly, I keep getting an error reading "npm ERR! missing script: start", but i definitely have the start script in my program, as you can see. I've looked through a couple other posts but nothing has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Check all the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631300/why-do-i-obtain-this-error-when-deploying-app-to-heroku | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832262/heroku-web-npm-err-missing-script-start/37832370