# Heroku deployment fails with "missing script: start"

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment, mean-stack

I am trying to upload my local MEAN stack based web application to my Heroku server. I have updated my code in Bitbucket and have successfully done the Heroku deployment part. But, the web app is still not live. When I hit the page, I am getting something like this:

[image: application error]

I then checked the logs by firing 'heroku logs' but I am unable to understand what the logs are trying to ask for. I am sharing the logs below:

[image: heroku logs]

As I understand it, the application was unable to find "start" but I have later exclusively added `"start" : "node app.js"` but I still don't see any difference in the heroku logs or in the heroku link.

Can anyone help with what am I doing wrong here?

here's my *package.json* file

```
{
  "start": "node app.js",
  "name": "PerosnalPro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Personal website using dynamic routing and responsive design.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Mikey",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^1.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.3.4",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://user@bitbucket.org/username/projectname"
  },
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/username/projectname"
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you added the missing `start` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637534/2745495) AND you pushed the change to heroku?

Comment: Yup the same way and exactly used the same reference @gino

Comment: share you package.json

Comment: @mehta-rohan - update the question

Comment: @Gino was right too.

Comment: Thanks Gino - as said by rohan you too were right. Have a great day to both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"scripts": {
     "start" : "node app.js", 
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified                   \" && exit 1"
 }
```

Add your start tag in scripts. :)

Comment: Thanks a ton Rohan - you saved the day for me. thanks alot.