# Deploy static web page with node.js http-server on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've run node.js [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), described in my web dyno: `http-server .build -p 80`
Well, I've tried to stop process, kill, scale web to 0, restart... Even if web.1 disappear from `heroku ps` list, server still working on 80 port. And it can't be restarted with new arguments because port is already in use and I have no way to stop it. What am I doing wrong?
I also tried to open heroku bash in admin panel and check `ps aux` or `netstat`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Sorry, I should not to specify port, because heroku uses random port, so my final dyno looks like this: `http-server .build -p $PORT`