# I got error while deploying my app on heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, deployment

Hey guys i got stuck in that error i did all the steps right but it still not work,my deploy failed after all this is the error i got, please help me i want to deploy my app for demonstration purposes i tried to reinstall my heroku cli and that does not work too

---

[here are the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9skt.png)

[what i got on the browser when i try to open the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ah7.png)

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637534/6392696

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashed and the logs do not show the real error, so you should SSH on the dyno to read the logs (they gave the path).

It's doable with the CLI: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec

Comment: yes exactly i don't see where is the error i'll check the link thanks

Answer (score 0):

What type of error you are facing. If this is about deploying and git push etc then tell me about the error.Please specify your problem.

Comment: Yes i got this after i did the commands to deploy my app it seems every thing is right to me but the deploy field